# Is it good to merge two database table?

Tags: mysql, database

We are working on ticket booking platform, where user selects the number of tickets, fills the attendee forms and makes the payment. On the database level, we are storing transaction entry for a single transaction in a table and multiple attendee entries in different table. So there is `one to many` relation between transaction table and attendee table.

**Transaction Table:**

```
txnId | order id | buyer name | buyer email | amount | txn_status | attendee json | ....
```

**Attendee Table:**

```
attendeeId | order id | attendee name | attende email | ......
```

Now you might be thinking "Why I have attendee json in transaction table?". Well the answer is, when user initiates the transaction, we store attendee data in json and we mark the transaction as INITIATED. After successful transaction, the same transaction will be marked as SUCCESS and attendee json will be saved in Attendee table. Plus, we use this json data to show attendee deatils to the organizer on dashboard , this way we saved a database hit on attendee table. And attendee json is not queryable that's why we had attendee table to fire required queries.

**Question:** Now for some reason we are thinking of merging these tables and removing the json column. And suppose if a transaction initiated for 4 attendees, we are thinking of creating four transaction entries. And we have algorithm to show these entries as a single on dashboard. How is it going to effect the performance if I go for this approach? What will be your suggestions?

**Now table will look like this:**

```
 txnId | order id | buyer name | buyer email | amount | txn_status | attendee name | attendee email ....
 1     | 123      | abc        | abc@abc.com | 100    | SUCCESS    | xyz           | xyz@xyz.com....
 2     | 123      | abc        | abc@abc.com | 100    | SUCCESS    | pqr           | pqr@pqr.com....
```

Comment: [Every non-key attribute must provide a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) attempts to organize the database to minimize redundancy.  The technique you're using is called [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and it's used to try and optimize reading tables by adding redundant data to avoid joins.  It's hotly debated when denormalization is appropriate.

In your case, there should be no performance issue with having two tables and a simple join so long as your foreign keys are indexed.

I would go so far as to say you should eliminate the `attendee json` column as it's redundant and likely to fall out of sync causing bugs.  The attendee table will need UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE triggers to keep it up to date slowing down writing to the table.  [Many databases have built in JSON functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) which can create JSON very quickly.  *At minimum* move the cached JSON to the attendee table.

In addition, you have `order id` in both the attendee and txn table hinting at another data redundancy.  `buyer name` and `buyer email` suggest that should also be split off into another table avoiding gumming up the txn table with too much information.

Rule of thumb is to work towards normalization unless you have solid data otherwise.  Use indexes as indicated by using EXPLAIN.  Then only denormalize only as much as you need to make the database perform as you need.  Even then, consider putting a cache on the application side instead.

You might be able to cheaply squeak some performance out of your database now, but you're mortgaging your future.  What happens when you want to add a feature that has to do with attendee information and nothing to do with transactions?  Envision yourself explaining this to a new developer...

> You get attendee information from the transaction table... buyer information, too.  But a single attendee may be part of multiple transactions, so you need to use DISTINCT or GROUP BY... which will slow everything down.  Also they might have slightly different information, so you have to use *insert complicated mess here* to figure that all out... which will slow everything down.  Why is it this way?  Optimization, of course!  Welcome to the company!